# How to keep from BeautifulSoup result just a part from HTML code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script which scrape data from a link.I have the folowing resultSet:

```html
<p class="flag"><img alt="Paris" src="/images/flags/FR.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Austria" src="/images/flags/AT.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Switzerland" src="/images/flags/CH.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Malta" src="/images/flags/MT.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Sydney" src="/images/flags/AU.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Rotterdam" src="/images/flags/NL.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="London" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="London" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="West + Wales" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Melbourne" src="/images/flags/AU.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="London" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Bulgaria" src="/images/flags/BG.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Amsterdam" src="/images/flags/NL.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Scotland" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
<p class="flag"><img alt="Midlands" src="/images/flags/UK.gif"/></p>
```

How can I keep as string/text only the following:

- FR
- AT
- CH
- etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all `img` elements having "flags" inside `src` attribute and located inside `p` element with `class="flag"`, then extract the language value from the `src` attribute value:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pattern = re.compile(r"/(\w+)\.gif$")
for img in soup.select("p.flag img[src*=flags]"):
    match = pattern.search(img["src"])
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
re.findall(r'src=".+?/(\w+)\.gif"', text)
```